# JWT Authentication - UserManager.GetUserAsync returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

In `AuthController` when authenticating I create a few *Claims* - `UserID` is one of them.

```
...
Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
  new Claim("UserID", user.Id.ToString()),
})
```

When Angular app makes request I am able to fetch `UserID` in another controller

```
Claim claimUserId = User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "UserID");
```

The `ControllerBase.User` instance holds `.Identity` object which in turn holds `Claims` collection.

- `Identity.IsAuthenticated` equals `True`.
- `Identity.Name` holds `admin` string (name of the relevant user).

If I try to fetch user like this:

```
var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)
```

the `user` is `null`.

Perhaps, I forgot to add some extra claim?

Or maybe, once I'm using JWT - I should override the default `UserManager` functionality so it fetches user by `claim` which holds `UserID`?

Or maybe there's a better approach?

Additional info:

The `Identity` is registered as follows

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

`ApplicationUser.Id` field is of `bigint` (or in C# of `long`) type

Also, I create users in `EF Seed Data` with UserManager which is resolved using `ServiceProvider`

```
_userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    ...
        adminUser.PasswordHash = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>().HashPassword(adminUser, "123qwe");
        _userManager.CreateAsync(adminUser);
```

Comment: Could you share how you register Identity?

Comment: hi @AlexRiabov, just answered your question, the code under `Additional Info` section.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[`UserManager.GetUserAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0) internally uses [`UserManager.GetUserId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserid?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to retrieve the user id of the user which is then used to query the object from the user store (i.e. your database).

`GetUserId` basically looks like this:

```
public string GetUserId(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    return principal.FindFirstValue(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType);
}
```

So this returns the claim value of `Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType`. `Options` is the [`IdentityOptions` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.0) that you configure Identity with. By default the value of `UserIdClaimType` is `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`, i.e. `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"`.

So when you try to use `UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)`, where that user principal has a `UserID` claim, the user manager is simply looking for a different claim.

You can fix this by either switchting to the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`:

```
new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
})
```

Or you configure Identity properly so it will use your `UserID` claim type:

```
// in Startup.ConfigureServices
services.AddIdentity(options => {
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = "UserID";
});
```

Comment: Alternatively..., if `userId` is not available, one can use `userManager.FindByNameAsync(username)` instead if that fits the business requirement.

Comment: Simply doing `new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id)` worked for me. Previously had this as `user.UserName`. Didn't realize the "name identifier" would be an Id. Who woulda thunk.

Comment: @mwilson How you use the claims mostly depends on your application. There are different ways to approach this, and it also depends on what your id is.

Comment: Great solution. In my case, the Startup.ConfigureServices solution worked for me. Setting a breakpoint in the controller and navigating through the User->claims helped me realize which claim type my organization was using to get the userid. Then setting options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.[option] did it for me.

Comment: `UserManager.GetUserAsync` eventually calls the method `FindByIdAsync` of the `IUserStore` implementation which is helpful to know if you need to debug a custom `IUserStore` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

When you create **Claims**, you just need to do like:

```
 List<Claim> claims = new()
 {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),  // This line is important.
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, jti)
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a tutorial that gave bad advice, it assigned a "general description" to the "sub" claim of the JWT-token.

A claim entry for `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` is automatically created from the "sub" claim in the JWT auth library, so it ended up double. One with incorrect value and one with correct.

**This was the incorrect implementation:**

```
   private Claim[] CreateClaims(IdentityUser user)
    {
        return new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
        };
    }
```

**This is the correct implementation:**

```
private Claim[] CreateClaims(IdentityUser user)
{
    return new[] {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
    };
}
```

**How the claims look with the correct implementation:**

[image: Claims]

Comment: I must have followed the same tutorial! Thanks so much for posting when you worked it out! Removing name identifier and replacing Sub value with the userId solved it for me!