# How to create identity user based on claims prinicpals

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using asp.net mvc with work/school accounts authentication. Currently I'm trying to implement identity into to the user process.

Here is my `ApplicationUser` class:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Semester> Semesters { get; set; }
}
```

So far, identity works just fine, there is just one problem. When I log into the app with my school account, I can call the `ClaimsPrincipals` as `User` in the Controllers. To get the current `ApplicationUser` you can use the `UserManager` (`await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)`, with `User` being the `ClaimsPrincipals`) But since I haven't stored my school account in the database, the result will be null. If I create a new `ApplicationUser` like the following

```cs
var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
{
    UserName = User.Identity.Name,
    Email = User.Identity.Name
};
await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser);
await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(newUser, User.Claims);
```

This will succesfully create and save the new user to the database with the claims. But then when I try to get the new created `ApplicationUser` with `await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` the result will still be null. If I access my `DbContext` and get all `ApplicationUsers`, the newly created `ApplicationUser` is there. So, how can I create an `ApplicationUser` based on the `ClaimsPrincipals` I get from my school account login?

Comment: may be you need to refresh claims as newly created user may not exist yet. if it was created fine in database, try refreshing claims using `await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(applicationUser);` after calling `await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(newUser, User.Claims);`

Comment: @Dave this gives me the following error: `InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.Application'. The registered schemes are: AzureAD, AzureADOpenID, AzureADCookie. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Identity.Application",...)?`. Based on that I had the idea to do `await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, loginInfo)`. But I don't know how to retreive the login information. `loginInfo` needs to be `UserLoginInfo`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot say what could be wrong. May be try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51386705)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @poke for this.

[`UserManager.GetUserAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0) internally uses [`UserManager.GetUserId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserid?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to retrieve the user id of the user which is then used to query the object from the user store (i.e. your database).

`GetUserId` basically looks like this:

```
public string GetUserId(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    return principal.FindFirstValue(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType);
}
```

So this returns the claim value of `Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType`. `Options` is the [`IdentityOptions` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.0) that you configure Identity with. By default the value of `UserIdClaimType` is `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`, i.e. `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"`.

So when you try to use `UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)`, where that user principal has a `UserID` claim, the user manager is simply looking for a different claim.

You can fix this by either switchting to the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`:

```
new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
})
```

Or you configure Identity properly so it will use your `UserID` claim type:

```
// in Startup.ConfigureServices
services.AddIdentity(options => {
    options.ClaimIdentity.UserIdClaimType = "UserID";
});
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51122850/3850405