# GetUserAsync returns null but FindByNameAsync works

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

Using .Net 6 and Identity, I am trying to retrieve my current user.

The following works

```
return await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
```

But GetUserAsync always return a null value

```
return await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
```

Why doesn't it work?

###### UPDATE with minimal code

This is my function:

```
public async Task<AppUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
        {           
            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            //line below returns null
            //return await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);

        }
```

I have commented the code which doesn't work.

And my AppUser:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string ISO2Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you Upload the minimal codes that could reproduce your error?I tried return await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User); it also works well in my case

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I have updated my question accordingly

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error ,but I found a related issue here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119926/jwt-authentication-usermanager-getuserasync-returns-null, maybe you could check the usr claims